# MS SQL Server query supended due to lock by negative spid (-2)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, jpa

Hello i have a following problem.

I am running a Java web programm with eclipse and i am using JPA for the sql transactions. For a specific table for which the programm does an insert happend an exception and the transaction was rolled back . From this moment i cannot do anything from the management studio.
I am trying to run a simple query (select * from table where) from the Microsoft sql management Studio but it is always pending Saying "Executing Query". Other tables work fine. I used activity monitor and for this query it says

```
Wait Type = "LCK_M_IS"

Wait Resource = "objectlock lockPartition=0 objid=612405451 subresource=FULL dbid=34 id=lock89b2d280 mode=X associatedObjectId=612405451    -2      16  MY_SERVER_CODE  internal "

BlockedBy = "-2"
```

Killing all conections,closing programms,restarting windows doenst seem to fix the problem. The **BlockedBy** field was supposed to show me the sid that was block my query but i cannot find anything about -2
any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been dealt by Paul Randal here :[Disaster recovery 101: dealing with negative SPIDS (-2 and -3)](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/disaster-recovery-101-dealing-with-negative-spids-2-and-3/)

> SPID -2 is an orphaned DTC transaction.A deferred transaction is one where the transaction could not be recovered fully becau
>   se of an I/O error or a gross file system problem like an unavailable file

Below are the steps to deal with negative spids

run below query

```
select request_owner_guid as [UoW ID] 
from sys.dm_tran_locks where
 request_session_id = -2
```

Then use kill like below

```
kill {UoW ID}
```

References:
http://www.eraofdata.com/sql-server/troubleshooting-sql-server/orphaned-msdtc-transactions-2-spids/